# Mercurial hg serve multiple repositories

Tags: mercurial

I am setting up a central mercurial server, and want to host multiple repositories.  Every web page I look at about this says to set up a config file that looks like this:

```
[collections]
repos/ = repos/
```

Where /repos is the folder and /repos is the path to use in the URL.

My question is which /repos is which???  I may want to use a name that is not the same as the path, as in:

```
[collections]
A/ = B/
```

Is A the physical path or the url path?  Such a simple question you would think would have been answered, but I could not find any nontrivial examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I got it.  This is on Windows, and here is everything that I need in the hg.conf file:

```
[paths]
foo = C:\Data\repositories-hg/foo-hg
bar = C:\Data\repositories-hg/bar-hg
```

This lets met access the repo at the location  C:\Data\repositories-hg/foo-hg as:

http://server:8000/foo

Therefore A is the url alias and B is the physical path.  There's of course more to set up, but this accomplishes what  need for now.